# Error loading the index.asp with global.asa

Tags: asp-classic, global.asa

I am trying to setup a classic asp application in IIS and I am unable to get it working.

I have tried the default document and changing the application pool to v2. It did not work. I changed the file name global.asa to global.asax thinking that it was supposed to be asax. The page loaded but there are some dependencies from the global.asa file which are not loaded as I changed to gloabl.asax.

with the global.asa file I am getting below error:

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact 
the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more 
about this error.
```

Why is it not working when I use the global.asa file. and how to get it working with the global.asa file.

Comment: You need to [enabled detailed errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629133/692942). You should never try to load `global.asa` directly, it is loaded by ASP automatically if it exists in the root of a Web Application *(any folder classed as an Application in IIS)*. Either the error is because you're trying to load it directly or the file contains an error.

Comment: I am loading the index.asp file as the default document and the global.asa contains just two methods which are `sub Application_OnStart` and `sub Session_OnStart` both of them do not have any code inside them. Still, I am having the same situation.

Comment: Have you enabled detail errors in IIS so we can get some feedback on the error? If you're loading the index.asp file what makes you think that global.asa is the issue?

Comment: I am saying that `global.asa` is the issue because, I see the issue only when the `global.asa` file is available in the root folder of the app.

Comment: I did enable detailed errors but it is redirecting to the 500 error page and did not give me details about the error.

Comment: I feel like we are going in circles, what does the 500 error page say? If you've enabled detailed errors it must say something other then the default blurb in the question.

Comment: I did set the error to detailed but the detailed error is not working. It has the Error 500 in the title of the tab and it says unable to load the page on the page. no information like null reference exception or syntax error or anything.

Comment: What Internet Browser are you using? If it's IE you may need to turn off ["Show Friendly Error Messages"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008842/692942) in the IE Advanced Settings. Also, with ASP you may need to tell it to [send errors to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851414/692942). There is already a massive thread about this topic which I've already linked, look through all the answers as they have useful bits of information.

Comment: After changing those settings I was able to get an error, but it did not show me an error like 500 with more details about the line of code, etc. But I was able to trace the issue by moving line by line code into a new empty `global.asa` file. The application did not load when I added the `#include` line, so found the server-side include and the enable parent folder needs to be done to get the includes working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trace the issue by moving line by line code into a new empty `global.asa` file.

The application did not load when I added the `#include` line, so found the server-side include by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640862/5198915) and the enable parent folder needs to be done to get the includes working by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24618621/5198915) and the instructions from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default).